# Create Javascript To Sort List alphabetycally

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Hello I would like to sort automatically in li.

I explain with an exemple.

Here, an exemple of code :

```
<ul class="uuuu">

    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Luffy
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            987
        </a>
    </li>   
    
    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            564
        </a>
    </li>   
    
    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Sabo
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Smoker
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Zorro
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

The result is

```
    Luffy
    987
    564
    Sabo
    Smoker
    Zorro
```

Now, I would like help for making a script in JS to sort and create the first letter automatically and alphabetically.

I would like to have this result :

```
    0-9
    
    564
    987

    L
    
    Luffy

    S
    
    Sabo
    Smoker

    Z
    
    Zorro
```

Thanks

I try some stuff but noting work

Comment: Thanks but I got an error. I dont know what to do :  -Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Get the <li> nodes:
let nodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul.uuuu li'))

// Sort them alphabetically:
nodes.sort(function(a, b){
    let word1 = a.querySelector('a').innerText.trim().toUpperCase()
    let word2 = b.querySelector('a').innerText.trim().toUpperCase()
    if ( word1 < word2 ) {
        return -1
    }
    if ( word2 < word1 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})

var lastLetter = ''
document.querySelector('ul.uuuu').innerHTML = ''

// Insert them back into the DOM:
nodes.forEach(function(node){
    let thisLetter = node.querySelector('a').innerText.trim().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase()
  
    // Decide whether to add a section header:
    if (
        thisLetter != lastLetter
    ) {
        if ( ! ( thisLetter.match(/[0-9]/) && lastLetter.match(/[0-9]/) ) ) {
            let newElmt = document.createElement('span')
            newElmt.innerText = ( thisLetter.match(/[0-9]/) ? '0-9' : thisLetter )
            document.querySelector('ul.uuuu').appendChild(newElmt)
        }
    }
    lastLetter = thisLetter // Remember which section we are up to

  // Insert this node:
    document.querySelector('ul.uuuu').appendChild(node)
})
```

```html
<ul class="uuuu">

    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Luffy
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            987
        </a>
    </li>   
    
    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            564
        </a>
    </li>   
    
    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Sabo
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Smoker
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="aaaaaa" id="xxxxxx">
        <a class="bbbbbb" href="ccccc" data-depth="1">
            Zorro
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks again. I still don't understand why I got this error on my test 
   
    Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Comment: I Finnaly found ! now I would like instead of a simple span, add the first letter in a class

Comment: You can add a class like this: `newElmt.className = 'myClassName'`.

Comment: perfect you are a king ! and now, how I can ignore the case ? because the difference between "Stefen" and "stefen" will be considered for 2 first different letter

Comment: @ArnSed I have added three calls to `.toUpperCase()` to ensure the comparisons are case-insensitive.